# Android - How to install signed APK on device?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm in the final stages of preparation for publishing my signed APK to the Android Market. In [Google's doc's](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/preparing.html) they say:

**10. Test your compiled and signed application**

*Before you release your compiled application, you should thoroughly test it on the target mobile device (and target network, if possible).*

So I have my compiled, release-signed, zipaligned APK ready to put on the Market. How do I get it onto my phone to test it?

Obviously, I can't simply load up my Eclipse project onto the phone (as I've been doing during development) because it loads the debug-signed APK file instead of the APK that has gone through the signing process and is ready to upload to the Android Market.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try `adb install MyApp.apk` in a shell from your ./bin folder while the phone is attached to USB.

If you experience problems due to certificate errors, you should run `adb uninstall your.package.id` before installing the new package.

Comment: SO has changed so you can't accept answers until about 10-15 minutes after the question is asked. Otherwise I of course would have done so sooner.

Comment: FYI on my Mac I found adb in ~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools