# Should you be able to install a digitally signed APK not from the Play Store?

Tags: android, apk, google-play

I emailed a final build, digitally-signed APK to a client. Should they be able to open it from  their email, or can you only open signed APKs in a shell [like mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772148/android-how-to-install-signed-apk-on-device) (or from the Play store of course)? They've been able to install APKs before now just from my emails, but they've never been digitally signed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the client gets the email on their phone, they should be able to open the .apk directly from their phone to install it.

You do need to allow the installation of **Unknown Sources** in **Settings => Application**

This is how a user installs the Amazon Marketplace, too. Amazon sends you an email where you can open the .apk file.

Comment: Thanks for that pointer. You helped get my mind thinking. The problem ended up being that the unsigned app was still on the device, so when they tried to install the signed version it failed because of the different signature. I had to have them install the old one entirely before installing the signed APK. That solves that mystery!

Answer (score 0):

Any one can copy signed apk file to Phone Sdcard, and then by clicking on this apk file in phone(from any of file explorer app), its installing Wizard will open for it self.  and will ask user to install the app.

user must be enabled installation of unknown source in settings.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse your client will be able to install your app. Just click on the .apk file in phone.